# Deleting cells and corresponding row if criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has columns from A5 to AA5 and has data from A6 to AA10000. In cells A1, a user inputs a value, in cell A2 is a drop box that contains the headers of columns X to AA (A, B, C, D), and in A3 I have a dropdown of logical operators (<,>,<>,=). I'm trying to write a script that goes through columns X to AA and remove the cells that met a criteria that a user sets, e.g. user inputs a value of 300, a header "B" and a logical operator "<" and the macro goes through column Y which has the header "B" and deletes all values that are less than 300, the deletes the row from A to AA.

So far I've attempted this:

```
Sub removedata()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim headerval As Variant
Dim sign As Variant
Dim inputval As Variant
Dim b_header As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("X5:AA5000")
Set b_header = ws.Range("X5:X5000")
inputval = cells(1, 1).Value
headerval = cells(2, 1).Value
sign = cells(3, 1).Value

For Each Cell In b_header.cells
    If (headerval = "B") And (sign = "<") And (inputval < Cell.Value) Then
        Cell.Delete
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

I've only attempted it for B column as a test to see whether or not I could get something to happen. When I run this Macro, it just buffers for a second and then nothing else happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Actually I realised it deletes the values that are greater than the input (Cell A1), however it only deletes a few of them each time I run it, it also moves the cells below it to its position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The COUNTIF/COUNTIFS worksheet function accepts and interprets criteria as strings. You can use with Evaluate or directly through an application object.

```
Option Explicit

Sub delSpecial()
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long, c As String, cl As Long
    With Worksheets("sheet6")
        c = .Cells(3, "A").Value & .Cells(1, "A").Value
        cl = Application.Match(.Cells(2, "A").Value, .Rows(5), 0)
        lr = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row)
        For i = lr To 6 Step -1
            If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Cells(i, cl), c)) Then
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 27).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                '.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!
If you don't mind, could you explain these lines to me:
c = .Cells(3, "A").Value & .Cells(1, "A").Value
cl = Application.Match(.Cells(2, "A").Value, .Rows(5), 0)
If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Cells(i, cl), c)) Then

Comment: The first is simple string concatenation of A3&A1 so c is `">=700"` The second uses the worksheet's MATCH function to return the column number that matches A2 in row 5 so column 25 or column Y.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry to keep bugging you, with this line "For i = lr To 6 Step -1", how come it's from i=lr To 6. I'm just confused about the 6 Step -1 section.

Comment: When you delete rows you always work from bottom to top or risk skipping over rows that have been removed. If you delete row 8, row 9 becomes row 8 and the next iteration examines row 9 so the row that was row 9 escapes examination.

Comment: Legend! That makes so much sense.

Comment: Hey Jeepad, is there a way so that if there is a range that was added one of the columns (e.g. values in X column can range from 50 to 100, but also include the user input and logical aspect like you showed in your original answer, to delete the rows (so every row that meets the user input criteria and is outside the boundary of 50 to 100 gets deleted). Each column for X to AA has a different range criteria. I originally tried using the "Data Validation" tool on Excel, but realised it was extremely wrong.

Comment: That sounds like a new question. It seems beyond the scope of a response in a comment.